# Number of FLOPs (floating point operations) for exponentiation

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, floating-point

What is the number of floating point operations needed to perform exponentiation (power of)?

Assuming multiplication of two floats use one FLOP, the number of operations for $x^n$ will be $n-1$. However, is there a faster way to do this? How does it work if $n$ isn't an integer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Assuming multiplication between two numbers use one FLOP, the number of operations for $x^n$ will be $n-1$. However, is there a faster way to do this ...

There most certainly is a faster way to do this for non-negative integer powers. For example, $x^{14}=x^{8}x^{4}x^{2}$. It takes one multiplication to compute $x^2$, one more to compute $x^4$, one more to compute $x^8$, and two more to multiple those three numbers. This suggests a simple cost and a simple algorithm.

- Convert the non-negative integer power to base 2.
- Count the number of ones in this representation.
- Add the power of two corresponding to the most significant non-zero bit in this representation.
- Subtract one.

This yields a concise algorithm for any non-negative integer power. This algorithm is the most efficient, up to $x^{14}$. This algorithm suggests six multiplications are needed to compute $x^{15}$ since $x^{15}=x^8x^4x^2x$. However, 15 is 120 in base 3 and 30 in base 5, both of which imply that only five multiplications are needed to compute $x^{15}$: $x^{15}=(x^3)^4x^3$ from the base three representation, and $x^{15}=(x^5)^3$ from the base five representation. The minimum number of multiplications needed to compute $x^n$ where $n$ is a non-negative integer is in fact an [NP-complete problem](https://oeis.org/A003313). But it's a whole lot less than $n-1$ multiplications.

> ... and how does it work if $n$ isn't an integer?

There are some tricks one can use if $n$ is a rational. But if $x$ is real and $n$ is a non-negative real, one must resort to approximation techniques. (For example, approximation techniques are used twice-fold in calculating $\exp(n\ln(x))$.)

Comment: Are you sure calculating the number of multiplications needed in NP-complete?  This seems like a problem dependent on factorization, which is believed to be NP-Intermediate.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the complexity of addition chains?

Comment: @stux: Just because factorizations yield candidate solutions does not imply that all solutions are based on factorization...

Comment: @user21820: that is very true, hence my question and wording. If all solutions are driven by factorization then the problem (most likely) cannot be NP-complete.  If it isn't, then the link provided does not include a reference proving NP-completeness.

Comment: @stux - Downey, Peter, Benton Leong, and Ravi Sethi. "Computing sequences with addition chains." SIAM Journal on Computing 10.3 (1981): 638-646.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Thank you!  Much obliged!

Answer (score 6):

Using n-1 multiplications would be rather daft. For example, if n = 1024, you just square x ten times. Worst case is 2 * log_2 (n). You can look up Donald Knuth, Art of Computer Programming, for some details how to do it faster. There are some situations, like n = 1023, where you would square x ten times giving x^1024, then divide by x.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why that didn't come to my mind...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the formula 
$$ x^y = \exp (y \ln x). $$

If you want to use only multiplications, when $n$ is a natural number you can use *repeated squaring*, that uses $O(\log n)$ multiplications. For other $n$, multiplication alone doesn’t suffice.

Answer (score 3):

People told you what happens when $n$ is an integer.

Regarding when it isn't, there may not even **exist** a way to do floating-point exponentiation at all.

It's called the [Table-Maker's Dilemma](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/LOG10HAF.TXT), which says the amount of memory you'd need is unbounded:

> No general
>       way exists to predict how many extra digits will have to be carried to
>       compute a transcendental expression and round it  *correctly*  to some
>       preassigned number of digits.
>       **Even the fact  (if true)  that a finite
>       number of extra digits will ultimately suffice may be a deep theorem.**

Comment: For floating point arithmetic it is obvious that a finite number of extra digits will suffice, because there is a finite set of inputs.

Comment: @gnasher729: Yeah... I wouldn't have posted this on StackOverflow, but given this was on CS.SE, I wasn't sure how literally to interpret the word "floating-point" in the question. I thought there's a decent chance it was just used as a synonym for "non-integer" so I figured I'd mention the transcendental case for completeness.

Comment: Possibly closely related to this is the (former) [extraordinary slowness of the former gcc math library implementation of `pow(x,y)` for some inputs](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13932). It tried very hard (arguably tried too hard) to chase down the elusive half an ULP accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about the problem, you may not try to find a solution with the lowest number of multiplications, but with the lowest execution time.

Consider a model where you can start a multiplication in every cycle, but each multiplication takes a fixed number of cycles, say 3 cycles. A method calculating x^n with k multiplications might take 3k cycles (if each multiplication depends on a result that was calculated just before), while a a method using more multiplications might run quicker.

For example: To calculate x^15, you might calculate in that order x^2 = x*x, x^3 = (x^2)*x, x^6 = (x^3)^2, x^7 = x^6 * x, x^14 = (x^7)^2, x^15 = x^14 * x. Six multiplications, but each dependent on the previous one.

Or you calculate x^2, x^4 = (x^2)^2, x^3 = x^2 * x, x^5 = (x^4)*x, x^15 = x^5 * x^3, so you have only four multiplications depending on previous results.

Comment: The last paragraph is erroneous. $x^5*x^3$ is $x^8$, not $x^{15}$. Calculating $x^{15}$ requires at least five multiplications (or four multiplications to yield $x^{16}$, followed by a division by $x$, but that's more expensive than five multiplications).